# Dornhoff definition of R-module in "Group representation theory"

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I have a question regarding the definition given by L. Dornhoff in his book: "Group representation theory", part A.

He states that "and additive abelian group M is called a module over a ring A (left A-module) if we have a multiplication $am \in M$, for $a\in A$, $m \in M$ such that $(a+a')m=am+a'm$, $a(a'm)=(aa')m$, $1m=m$".

However, the definition of A-module that I know also requires also (as an axiom) that $a(m+m')=am+am'$ and, as far as I tried, I couldn't derive this last one from the others.

My questions are: did he forget to include this last axiom? Or it is possible to derive it from the others? Or maybe it is a weaker valid definition suitable for his purposes?

If anyone knows, it would help a lot

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I guess he did forget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not it follows from the other axioms (which I strongly doubt, though I'm not interested enough to concoct a formal counter-example... since it wouldn't really mean anything), surely that property is desired/intended/required of modules over rings.

In fact, I'd think it was/is so strongly intended that the writer lost interest in spelling out "the usual details" before quite finishing. :)